# Apache ModSecurity: 403 Forbidden / MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR when sending multipart/form-data through ajax

Tags: ajax, apache

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('data', tmp_img);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'upload-image.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log('response: ' + xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        console.error('Request failed');
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
```

> ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Match of "eq 0" against "MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR" required. [file "/etc/modsecurity/12_HTTP_Protocol.conf"] [line "30"] [id "210240"] [rev "4"] [msg "WAF: Multipart request body failed strict validation: PE 1, BQ 0, BW 0, DB 0, DA 0, HF 0, LF 0, SM , IQ 0, IH 0, FLE 0||www.domain.net|F|2"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "CWAF"] [tag "Protocol"] [hostname "www.domain.net"] [uri "/upload-image.php"] [unique_id "ZGZ341JiiOsAAFudBsUAAAAO"]

May this be caused by a missing header? As I understand there are not mandatory ones.
I mean, the error is definitively triggered by setting the content-type, but perhaps I should add some extra headers along this one?
I have uploaded to the same server using a regular HTML form and it works just fine.

Comment: Yes, it looks like some headers are missing. Can you show full request including all headers?

Comment: That's all the log I have I'm afraid.

Comment: I suggest you to see what headers were send by a browser and then add them one by one to your script until it get through. Like this you will find which header is needed to pass the firewall.